# Let $M =\{ f(x)\in P_3 | \int_0^1f(x)dx = 0\}$ Find basis for M.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, solution-verification

Let $M =\{ f(x)\in P_3 | \int_0^1f(x)dx = 0\}$ Find basis for M.

solution:

$P_3$ is the set of all polynomials of degree strictly less than 3, ($f(x) = a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$).

hence, $\int_0^1f(x)dx = \frac{a_2}{3}+\frac{a_1}{2}+a_0$

$(1/3, 1/2, 1)*(a_2,a_1,a_0)^T$. Let $a_0 = t, a_1 = v$, then $a_2 = -3t+\frac{3}{2}v$. hence the basis is $\{(-3,0,1),(\frac{3}{2},1,0)\}$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basis for a vector space $V$ should consists of vectors in $V$. In your question, the basis should consists of polynomials in $P_3$, not column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. A basis should be
$$\{-3x^2+1, 3x^2+2x\}$$